# css - How to center Font Awesome icons in a td?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome for my icons and a simple table.

how can I make this icon be in the center of the `td` ? 
I was trying use `text-align: center`, but did not work.

Someone has a better idea how to fix this?

thank you.

jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/s15dxabc/

```css
table i {
  color: red;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td> this icon should be in the center</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `text-align: center` for your `td`, not for `i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `align:center` attribute in `td`

```css
table i {
  color: red;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td> this icon should be in the center</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or `text-align:center` in `td` css

```css
table i {
  color: red;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
table td {  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td> this icon should be in the center</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS

```
.center-table td{
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

In the table add a class

```
<table class="center-table">
```